# ClickHouse: How to move data from tables with different partition keys?

Tags: clickhouse

I'm planning on doing a table redesign in ClickHouse to avoid some performance and deduplication/versioning issues while using ReplicatedReplacingMergeTree. Here, OPTIMIZE FINAL can be run to remove duplicates but can't be run continuously.

So we are planning to keep a table A, partitioned daily, with incoming data.
Then a table B, partitioned monthly, where historical data will be stored.
Queries will be directed to a MERGE table (not MergeTree) that will contain both.

And then, we'd set up an action to move the latest partition, from A to B, every day right after the end of the day.

However, moving partition as in [MOVE PARTITION TO TABLE](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/statements/alter/#alter_move_to_table-partition) where it is stated that "Both tables must have the same partition key.", it is not possible.
An approach is to copy data from A's daily partition to B, and then detach/drop daily partition in A. However in the meantime we'll see duplicates.

What would be the best way to transfer this data from A to B with minimal impact? What other options would be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> An approach is to copy data from A's daily partition to B, and then 
>   detach/drop daily partition in A. However in the meantime we'll see duplicates.

you can copy data to an intermediate/temporary table TB (the same structure / partitioning as B). Then drop partition in A, then move from TB to B

Comment: However in this case, we're moving the whole monthly partition to B. First time is OK, but 2nd day in the month there would be already a monthly partition in B for that month. So in this case, I'd have to accumulate full month in intermediate table, keep it there during the month, and flush to B at the end of the month, including it in the Merge table, right? Then after moving to B at the end of the month, intermediate table can be flushed - rinse and repeat :)  But in this case we also have the initial problem in the copy from A to TB.

Comment: https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/statements/alter/#alter_attach-partition-from
you can use ATTACH PARTITION FROM

Comment: Though,   MOVE PARTITION also don't remove data from B. So, I don't see why you need to move whole month. I think you can do it daily by adding one day to B and removing one from A.

Comment: Thanks. It looks like MOVE PARTITION does remove (and I expect, atomically, hence my interest): `This query moves the data partition from the table_source to table_dest with deleting the data from table_source.`. With ATTACH PARTITION FROM I'd need the TB for changing partition key, but it looks like it would work, thanks! There would be duplicates during that "changing" time, though.